# Symfony2 FOSRest controller as service has an empty container

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have registered my controller as a service so I can have my repository injected into my controller. This all seems to work fine, except that now when i try to return the view it bugs on returning data.

It gives an error and tries to load `fos_rest.view_handler`:

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

The get is being called in the symfony2 controller class on `$this->container->get($id)`. For some reason the `ContainerInterface` is not being injected in the `ContainerAware` anymore when I use my controller as a service.

Has anyone experienced this problem before? How can I make sure the same container gets injected?

This is how I declared my class as a service:

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="acme.users.apibundle.controller.user_controller" class="Acme\Users\ApiBundle\Controller\UserController">
            <argument type="service" id="acme.users.user_repository"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

And this is my controller:

```
class UserController extends FOSRestController
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $users = $this->repository->findAll();

        $view = $this->view($users, 200)
                 ->setTemplate("MyBundle:Users:getUsers.html.twig")
                 ->setTemplateVar('users');

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the container into your controller using a `call` so that it is available in the `handleView` method.

Change your config to..

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
<services>
    <service id="acme.users.apibundle.controller.user_controller" class="Acme\Users\ApiBundle\Controller\UserController">
        <argument type="service" id="acme.users.user_repository"/>
        <!-- inject the container via the setContainer method -->
        <call method="setContainer">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        </call>
    </service>
</services>
```

Comment: I was afraid of that, is there no way that we can do this automatically when ContainerAware gets loaded anywhere?

Comment: ContainerAware won't change the service - you have to call setContainer. You can also manually inject the ViewHandler, build the view and so have the entire controller service driven, not extending FOSRestController. Example: LiipHelloBundle has some examples

Comment: You could listen to the `kernel.controller` event, check whether the controller has the `ContainerAwareInterface` and inject the container there. Alternatively you could inject the view handler in your `__construct` and over ride the `handleView` method using that service rather than the container call.

Comment: You could override the controller resolver that the kernel request dispatcher uses.  Hardly worth the effort though.